Unable to create CosmosDB database via go sdk
From Mac OS X, using the emulator for Azure CosmosDB running on a Docker container locally, I am able to use the explorer web portal to create a database.  However, I am unable to use the Azure Go SDK to create a database, but the errors don't present that there was an issue creating the db.
Besides this, there are multiple SDKs and a lot of the documentation has mistakes in it, is there a canonical source where I can see a functioning Golang example of utilizing the CosmosDB emulator?

cred, err := azcosmos.NewKeyCredential(cosmosDbKey)
    handle(err)
    client, err := azcosmos.NewClientWithKey(cosmosDbEndpoint, cred, nil)
    handle(err)

    databaseProperties := azcosmos.DatabaseProperties{ID: "databaseName"}
    databaseResponse, err := client.CreateDatabase(context.Background(), databaseProperties, nil)

How can I get better visibility into what is going on here, the client is able to create even if I pass in empty strings instead of the proper key and endpoint.
Tried to use the Go SDK to create a database, was expecting it to appear in the emulator portal.  I would also expect NewClientWithKey() to fail when the credentials are invalid, this is not the case.

Please make sure you use the correct tag. Cosmos is not for Azure CosmosDB

The code below interacts with Azure Cosmos DB or Azure Cosmos DB Emulator and creates a new database in Azure Cosmos DB or Azure Cosmos DB Emulator.

I used this link for Azure Cosmos DB Emulator to develop applications locally and test them with a working database.
If you are using Azure Cosmos DB Emulator, use the URI or Endpoint of Azure Cosmos DB Emulator as "https://localhost:8081" and use the Key of Azure Cosmos DB Emulator key.

Azure Cosmos DB emulator:

The package used is "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/data/azcosmos".
go get -u github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/data/azcosmos

package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/data/azcosmos"
)

func handle(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    const (
        cosmosDbEndpoint = "your_cosmosdb_endpoint" 
        cosmosDbKey      = "your_cosmosdb_key"
        dbName           = "samdb1"
    )

    // Create a new client with the account key
    cred, err := azcosmos.NewKeyCredential(cosmosDbKey)
    handle(err)
    client, err := azcosmos.NewClientWithKey(cosmosDbEndpoint, cred, nil)
    handle(err)

    // Create a new database
    databaseProperties := azcosmos.DatabaseProperties{ID: dbName}
    _, err = client.CreateDatabase(context.Background(), databaseProperties, nil)
    handle(err)

    log.Println("Database created successfully:", dbName)
}

Output:

Azure Cosmos DB account:


Thanks, yes what helped immensely was using _, err = client.CreateDatabase, because before I was not using _ and thus I had no visibility into the error.

Glad to know ☺️.
